# Rack app error: ActionController::UnknownHttpMethodをrescueする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Rack app error: ActionController::UnknownHttpMethodをrescueするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

指定されたHTTP method以外でアクセスするとこのエラーが出ます。その際に各種のバージョンなどがクライアント側に出力されるのでこれをrescueして、単純なエラーメッセージだけに変更したいと考えています。

midlewareから出されているエラーのようで
app/controllers/application_controller.rb
に
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod, with: :unknown_method
としても反応しません。

どうすればいいのでしょうか？

エラーログ

```
2016-01-06 22:22:28 +0800: Rack app error: #<ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod: AAA, accepted HTTP methods are OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK, VERSION-CONTROL, REPORT, CHECKOUT, CHECKIN, UNCHECKOUT, MKWORKSPACE, UPDATE, LABEL, MERGE, BASELINE-CONTROL, MKACTIVITY, ORDERPATCH, ACL, SEARCH, MKCALENDAR, and PATCH>
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:344:in `check_method'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:105:in `request_method'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:51:in `started_request_message'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `block in call_app'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:372:in `add'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/logger.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in broadcast'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/logger.rb:434:in `info'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `call'
/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Ruby 2.2.3
Rails 4.2.4
puma 2.15.3

「Rails の rescue_from で拾えない例外を exceptions_app で処理する」
http://qiita.com/ma2ge/items/938d9f8f4839eb336318

こちらを参考にしてRails.configuration.exceptions_appを設定しましたが、まったく反応せず上記のエラーログが出てきます。エラーはcurlコマンドを使って

```
$ curl -X AAA http://localhost:3000/
```

などとして例外になるようなHTTPメソッドを使ってコールしています。この時のエラーを捕捉したいのですが、まったくできません。なにがおかしいのでしょうか？

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-dispatch  の対策はすでに試した後での質問、ということでしょうか？　参照リンク先のconfig設定で言うと「config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses」のところです。この説明を信じるならば、HTTPメソッド例外をHTTPのレスポンスステータスに置き換えて処理をすることならできるみたいです。が、ご希望通りの処置とは違うかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうござます。ただおっしゃるようにちょっと意図している処理とは異なるようです。config.action_dispatch.rescue_re‌​sponsesの設定も試しましたが、そもそもなぜUnknownHttpMethodがrescueできないのか、が理解できていません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> これをrescueして、単純なエラーメッセージだけに変更したい

というのであれば、微妙に求めている回答とは違うかもしれませんが、こちらのページが参考になるかもしれません。

[Render 405 response for ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod exceptions](https://gist.github.com/viola/1243572)

試しにこちらでも組み込んでみました。

```
# lib/http_method_not_allowed.rb

class HttpMethodNotAllowed
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if !ActionDispatch::Request::HTTP_METHODS.include?(env["REQUEST_METHOD"].upcase)
      Rails.logger.info("ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod: #{env.inspect}")
      [405, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Method Not Allowed"]]
    else
      @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
      [@status, @headers, @response]
    end
  end
end

# config/application.rb
require 'http_method_not_allowed'
config.middleware.insert_before(0, HttpMethodNotAllowed)
```

実行結果

```
$ curl -X AAA http://localhost:3000/              
Method Not Allowed%
```

ログ

```
ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod: {"GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.1", "PATH_INFO"=>"/", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"::1", "REMOTE_HOST"=>"::1", "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"AAA", "REQUEST_URI"=>"http://localhost:3000/", ...（以下省略）
```

コードはこちらに置いてあります。

[JunichiIto/unknown-http-method-sandbox](https://github.com/JunichiIto/unknown-http-method-sandbox)

ご参考までに。

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました。わざわざサンプルのコードまで作成いただいて、感激いたしました。